# ¿Cómo hacer transparente un JTable?

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente codigo y el `JTable` no se hace tranparente. Usé `setOpaque(false)` en la clase `Lamina` pero no funciona:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class PrimeraClase {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ventana marco=new ventana();
        marco.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}

class ventana extends JFrame{

    public ventana(){
        dimensionesPantalla medidaP=new dimensionesPantalla();  
        int m=medidaP.ancho();
        int n=medidaP.alto();
        medidaP.Icono(this);
        setSize(m/2,n/2);   
        setLocation(m/4,n/4);
        setResizable(true);// si se puede cambiar el tamaño de la ventana
        setTitle("ventana");
        insertaImagen l=new insertaImagen(m/2,n/2,this);
        Lamina lamina1=new Lamina(m/2,n/2);
        this.add(lamina1);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Lamina extends JPanel{
    public  Lamina(int a,int b){
        setOpaque(false);
        Tabla nueva =new Tabla(3*a/4,b/4,this);
    }
}

class Tabla {
    private String [][] Datos=new String[10][20];
    private JTable Tabla1;
    String [] Cabezera =  {"Codigo","Rut","Nombre","Apellido","","","","","",""};

    public Tabla(int d, int f,Lamina g){
        Tabla1=new JTable(Datos,Cabezera);
        JScrollPane JS=new JScrollPane(Tabla1);
        JS.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(d,f));
        g.add(JS);
    }
}

class insertaImagen{
    public insertaImagen(int f,int g,JFrame d){
        Image Imagen = new ImageIcon("ecuacion.png").getImage();
        Image otraimg = Imagen.getScaledInstance(f,g,java.awt.Image.SCALE_FAST);
        ImageIcon otroicon = new ImageIcon(otraimg);
        JLabel Img=new JLabel(otroicon);
        d.add(Img);
    }
}

class dimensionesPantalla{
    Dimension tamañoPantalla;
    Toolkit dimensionPantalla;
    public dimensionesPantalla(){ 
       dimensionPantalla = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(); 
       tamañoPantalla= dimensionPantalla.getScreenSize();
    }

    public int alto(){
        int alturaPantalla=tamañoPantalla.height;
        return alturaPantalla;
    }

    public int ancho(){
        int anchoPantalla=tamañoPantalla.width;
        return anchoPantalla;
    }

    public void Icono(JFrame l){
        Image foto=dimensionPantalla.getImage("foto.jpg");
        l.setIconImage(foto);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Antes de nada, decirte que deberías seguir la convención de nombres del lenguaje, donde el nombre de las variables deben ir en minúsculas. La tabla será transparente si ni ella ni las celdas son opacas. Donde *table* es el nombre del `JTable`:

```
table.setOpaque(false);
((DefaultTableCellRenderer)table.getDefaultRenderer(Object.class)).setOpaque(false);
```

Si la tabla está en un `ScrollPane`, también debe ser transparente:

```
scrollPane.setOpaque(false);
scrollPane.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
```

Por último, tú puedes remover las líneas de la cuadrícula:

```
table.setShowGrid(false);
```

Comment: Hago lo que me dices y no funciona.